# How to add a value to each part in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array, append

I need to add a different value to each part of an array.

```
array1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,13]]
array2 = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"]]
```

Desired output:

```
array3 = [["a",1,2,3], ["b",4,5,6], ["c",7,8,9], ["d",10,11,13]]
```

The first array is built by scraping with Beautiful Soup so it is undefined until appended by the scrape. Not sure if that matters a great deal, but above is correct dimensions once the scrape is complete. I've been trying to use append, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: what does this have to do with `dictionary`?

Comment: I didn't mean to add that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and add the sub lists together:

```
array3 = [from_a2 + from_a1 
          for from_a2, from_a1 in zip(array2,array1)
         ]
```

note if you wanted to make this a dict, zip would work there too since the constructor can take `(key,value)` iterables:

```
data = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase,array1))

>>> data
{'d': [10, 11, 13], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

In this case I am using `string.ascii_lowercase` to be just all the letters until `array1` is finished although it would fail if `len(array1)>26` in which case you would need to use something with more labels.

Comment: This worked!! I've never used zip before and now it's my friend. Thank you so much.

Comment: note that zip will stop at the shortest iterable if they have different lengths, so you could implement a similar version with `string.ascii_lowercase` if that was all the labels are.